# IBM Watson Conversation : Intent is not triggering the dialog, all user inputs lead to anything_else

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I'm a complete newb in this field, so started with the tutorial in the documentation. [This](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/tutorial-dialog.html) is the page where I'm having problem.

I'm able to create the welcome dialog, and changes in the anything_else dialog are reflecting fine. But when I create a new dialog and set the trigger to the intent, it does not work. I've tried typing in the name, copy pasting it, clicking on (create new condition) and not. Tried different browsers and restarted project too.

There is a dropdown on the text that I type in the bot panel that says choose intent name and gives the list of two intents I've made. When I try clicking on the intent it's supposed to be in, I get this error :

Unable to change the intent. Error: Unique Violation: The value "good morning" already exists

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and googling it gives no result! Comment sections on different websites too seem to be having no problem with it as well.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit : JSON as downloaded from the project menu:

```
{"name":"Car tutorial","created":"2017-04-30T16:42:55.215Z","intents":[{"intent":"greeting","created":"2017-04-30T17:50:08.575Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:50:08.575Z","examples":[{"text":"Good afternoon","created":"2017-04-30T17:50:08.575Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:50:08.575Z"},{"text":"Good evening","created":"2017-04-30T17:50:08.575Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:50:08.575Z"},{"text":"Good morning","created":"2017-04-30T17:50:08.575Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:50:08.575Z"},{"text":"Hello","created":"2017-04-30T17:50:08.575Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:50:08.575Z"},{"text":"Hi","created":"2017-04-30T17:50:08.575Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:50:08.575Z"}],"description":null},{"intent":"turn_on","created":"2017-04-30T17:49:26.312Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:49:26.312Z","examples":[{"text":"Air on please","created":"2017-04-30T17:49:26.312Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:49:26.312Z"},{"text":"I need lights","created":"2017-04-30T17:49:26.312Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:49:26.312Z"},{"text":"Listen to some music","created":"2017-04-30T17:49:26.312Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:49:26.312Z"},{"text":"Play some tunes","created":"2017-04-30T17:49:26.312Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:49:26.312Z"},{"text":"Turn on the headlights","created":"2017-04-30T17:49:26.312Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:49:26.312Z"}],"description":null}],"updated":"2017-04-30T17:56:05.345Z","entities":[{"entity":"appliance","values":[{"value":"air conditioning","created":"2017-04-30T17:51:41.232Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:51:41.232Z","metadata":null,"synonyms":["air"]},{"value":"headlights","created":"2017-04-30T17:51:41.232Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:51:41.232Z","metadata":null,"synonyms":["lights"]},{"value":"music","created":"2017-04-30T17:51:41.232Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:51:41.232Z","metadata":null,"synonyms":["radio"]}],"created":"2017-04-30T17:51:41.232Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:51:41.232Z","metadata":null,"description":null},{"entity":"genre","values":[{"value":"classical","created":"2017-04-30T17:52:56.711Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:52:56.711Z","metadata":null,"synonyms":["symphonic"]},{"value":"rhythm and blues","created":"2017-04-30T17:52:56.711Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:52:56.711Z","metadata":null,"synonyms":["r&b"]},{"value":"rock","created":"2017-04-30T17:52:56.711Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:52:56.711Z","metadata":null,"synonyms":["pop"]}],"created":"2017-04-30T17:52:56.711Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:52:56.711Z","metadata":null,"description":null}],"language":"en","metadata":null,"description":"","dialog_nodes":[{"go_to":null,"output":{"text":{"values":["Hi! What can I do for you?"],"selection_policy":"sequential"}},"parent":null,"context":null,"created":"2017-04-30T17:55:24.851Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:55:48.868Z","metadata":null,"conditions":"#greeting","description":null,"dialog_node":"node_3_1493574922154","previous_sibling":"node_1_1493574794528"},{"go_to":null,"output":{"text":{"values":["I'm sorry, I don't understand. Please try again."],"selection_policy":"sequential"}},"parent":null,"context":null,"created":"2017-04-30T17:53:39.404Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:56:05.345Z","metadata":null,"conditions":"anything_else","description":null,"dialog_node":"node_5_1493574962852","previous_sibling":"node_3_1493574922154"},{"go_to":null,"output":{"text":{"values":["Welcome to the car demo!"],"selection_policy":"sequential"}},"parent":null,"context":null,"created":"2017-04-30T17:53:17.084Z","updated":"2017-04-30T17:53:57.004Z","metadata":null,"conditions":"welcome","description":null,"dialog_node":"node_1_1493574794528","previous_sibling":null}],"workspace_id":"2b6d0fdd-c04f-40e0-9310-0bba1ad38cef","counterexamples":[]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on attached JSON, your problem is that Watson conversation is stuck in the training process (if the pink message is showing a long time, that means he stuck).
[image]

I cannot explain why it happened. But I know the solution, just use "conversation_start" instead of "welcome" trigger

Comment: I changed it to conversation_start and it is still not working. It triggers the welcome message when the bot starts but again on all responses I get the anything_else node. The purple bar that says watson is training is still there btw. And I think you are right, that is the main problem.

Comment: try to remove this node completely

Comment: but that's strange, i just renamed the trigger and then after 1 -2 mins of training it's working now

Comment: No, the training is still not done. I tried deleting the conversation_start node, and now the anything_else triggers on load as well as for all responses. Can it be a problem it the workspace settings maybe?

Comment: Try to export, delete and import again whole project

Comment: And it's working!

So I think the german server on which I had made my instance was a problem because it failed when I tried doing what you said on it again. US South seems good tho. 

Thanks a bunch!

PS - does this happen regularly tho? anyplace I can track the servers health?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you placed "anything_else" node above your intent node.
Anything_else should be the latest node, because watson is executing it sequentional, once he will find match, it will go into.

Be sure, that you have the same order:
[image]

Comment: Hello,
thanks for your reply!
No the order is as you say; first node is welcome node, then the one that is not working, and at the last is the anything_else node.

Comment: In this case, can you please go to your project menu, and click "Download as JSON" and attach exported project file here. It will help us to debug